# Remove generic tags: [loop], [controller]

Tags: support, tag-cleanup

The tags [loop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loop) and [controller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controller) are both common English words that have not been used in any particular consistent fashion. ([controller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controller) even has a description saying not to use it.)

I went through both of them and retagged many questions; the remainder are generally either adequately tagged other than these or such low quality that they really shouldn't be edit-bumped.

I'd like to request that these tags be deleted by moderator action (burninated), and blacklisted if you see fit.